# Can C# windows form application can run Tablet Device Of Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, tablet

Can C# windows form application .exe can run Tablet Device  Of Windows 10 or not?

On Normal PC windows 10,I test it can run.

On a Windows 10 tablet device I haven't tested yet.

Please tell me if it can run or not.

Answer (score 0):

Tablets are normal Windows 10 devices so C# applications should work fine. Most small 8" devices are 32Bit, so make sure you compile it for AnyCPU/x86 and not for x64 only. Now they work on 64Bit PCs/2in1 and smaller 32Bit 8" tablets.